# Genymotion virtual device hangs when trying to use Surfeasy VPN or DriodVPN apps

Tags: android, vpn, genymotion

I'm using genymotion on my Ubuntu 15.04. On my (college)network I cannot use whatsapp etc... So, on my real android phone, I use Surfeasy VPN app. But when I do the same on Google Nexus 10-5.0.0 virtual device in genymotion, everything works fine until the last step(Adding routes..) after which it hangs and displays a black screen. I tried using DroidVPN where it hangs at Authenticating... step. Does using "surfeasy for pc" solve the issue? why do I get this problem?
please help me out.
PS: openvpn isn't compatible with the device.

Comment: Works fine with "Secure VPN" app.